# React final form - Unable to pass function to oChange prop

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I have a  in a form using react final form. I'm trying to pass the value of the current input to a function thats used when the field value changes. However when I type, it's taking no input.

```
 <Field name="myField">
     {({ input, meta }) => (
         <div>
             <TextField
                 type="text"
                 name={input.name}
                 value={input.value}
                 onChange={() =>
                     handleChange(input.value)
                 }
                 label="Title"
             />
         </div>
      )}

</Field>
```

I have a function handleChange above the render method. All I want to do is console the current value, and use a setState hook to update a state variable.

```
function handleChange(item: string) {
    setTitle(item);
    console.log(item);
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use a useEffect to achieve this, but the issue is that once you add your own useEffect onto it, then it overrides the default action which saves the form value to the form itself.

So first you still have to do the default onChange. And you want to take the value from the input field using e.target.value.

In your example, you are passing the value of the input field into your handeChange, but becuase you arent saving the value back into the input and the form, its always going to be empty.

```js
  <Field name="myField">
    {({input}) => (
      <div>
        <TextField
          name={input.name}
          value={input.value}
          onChange={(e, val) => {
            console.log(e.target.value);
            handleChange(e.target.value)
            input.onChange(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </div>
    )}
  </Field>
```